# while loop and array causes echo to not work

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have 2 problems with my code below:

Problem 1:

For questionId, it is not displaying the correct question number. Lets say I have 2 questions. Then for question 1, questionId should be '1' but instead it displays '3' Another example is that if I have 7 questions, then for question 1, questionId should be '1' but it displays '8' instead.

How can this be fixed?

Problem 2:

My $questionsql is only echoing 1 question, even if I have multiple questions to echo. What am I doing wrong and can I show all the questions rather than only 1 question.

Example:

If I have 2 questions which is:

```
Question 1: 

SessionId   QuestionId   QuestionContent    OptionId

ABV         1            What is my name?   O6   

Question 2: 

SessionId   QuestionId   QuestionContent    OptionId

ABV         2            What is my age?   O9
```

Then in the echo $questionsql it should display:

INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionId, QuestionContent, OptionId) VALUES ('ABV' ,'1','What is my name?','O6'), ('ABV' ,'2','What is my age?','O9')

But it is not displaying the above, instead it is displaying this below which is incorrect as it displays wrong question number and it displays only 1 question which is the latest question added.

INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionId, QuestionContent, OptionId) VALUES ('ABV' ,'3','What is my age?','O9')

UPDATE

Below is code, how can the 2 problems be fixed:

```
  foreach($_POST['questionText'] as $i => $question)
{

      $insertquestion = array();


$options[] = $_POST['gridValues'];

switch ($options[$i]){

    case "3": 
    $selected_option = "A-C";
    break;

    case "4": 
    $selected_option = "A-D";
    break;

    case "5": 
    $selected_option = "A-E";
    break;

    default:
    $selected_option = "";
    break;

}      

$optionquery = "SELECT OptionId FROM Option_Table WHERE (OptionType = '". mysql_real_escape_string($selected_option)."')";

 $optionrs = mysql_query($optionquery);
 $optionrecord = mysql_fetch_array($optionrs);
 $optionid = $optionrecord['OptionId']; 


    $insertquestion[] = "'". mysql_real_escape_string( $_SESSION['id'] ) . ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '') ."' ,'". mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['num_questions'] ) ."','".  mysql_real_escape_string( $question ) ."','".  mysql_real_escape_string( $optionid ) ."'";

    $questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionId, QuestionContent, OptionId) 
    VALUES (" . implode('), (', $insertquestion) . ")";

    $i++;

    }

echo($questionsql);
```

Below is the form code. How it works is the user types in a question in the textarea ('name='questionText') and types in an option (name='gridValues') and then they append them two in a table row (table in the form which id='qandatbl'). This is the question 1. Then they do the same again for second question, then third and etc. Please look at this carefully, it is easy to follow :)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `$i=0;` just before the `switch` statement, and inside your `foreach` loop, so you end up creating just the first element in your arrays.

No worries! I do this all the time!

Comment: Hi, where am I suppose to put the $i=0;? after the foreach loop?

Comment: I meant the foreach sorry :), it still did not work though, I tested this earlier and it didn't change anything?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, basically there are two problems here.  The first is that on every cycle of your primary loop, you're resetting `$i`.  You need to make it the key way you find the value you want:

```
foreach($_POST['questionText'] as $i => $question)
{

   $insertquestion = array();

   $options[] = $_POST['gridValues'];

   switch ($options[$i]){

   ...
```

I'm assuming here that your `gridValues` input and your `questionText` input correspond to one another, i.e. for the first gridValue you also want the first questionText.

The second thing which seems wrong is that you're assembling your SQL query as an array.  What you need to do is make a separate query for each iteration of your loop:

```
   $insertquestion = "'". mysql_real_escape_string( $_SESSION['id'] ) . ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '') ."' ,'". mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['num_questions'] ) ."','".  mysql_real_escape_string( $question ) ."','".  mysql_real_escape_string( $optionid ) ."'";

   $questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionId, QuestionContent, OptionId) 
  VALUES (" . implode('), (', $insertquestion) . ")";

   $i++;

}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried what you have stated but it is still doing same thing. I will update the code I above to what it is now at the moment and I will show you the form code in the question above. Give me 5 mins